# Python SQlite3 Update No Error But Does Not Updating

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update, where-clause

It shows no error and is able to run, but the data in the SQLite table doesn't update. However other update function similar to this work

```
def seller_edit():
    while True:
        sellername = str(input("Enter your username: "))
        with sqlite3.connect(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\HFSystem\Assginment\HFuserinfo.db") as connect:
            cursor = connect.cursor()
        check = "SELECT * FROM sellerinfo WHERE Username = ?"
        cursor.execute(check,[sellername])

        results = cursor.fetchall()

        if results:
            Phone = int(input("Enter New Phone No.: "))      
            Email = str(input("Enter New Email: "))
            Address = str(input("Enter New Address: "))
      

            updateseller ="""UPDATE sellerinfo SET Phone = ?, Email=?,Address=? WHERE Username=?"""
            
            cursor.execute(updateseller,[sellername,Phone,Email,Address])       
            connect.commit()
            print("Seller Info Edited!")
            connect.close()
            seller_info_menu()
            break

        else:
            print("ProductID does not recognised")
            option = input("Do you want to try again (y/n): ")
            if option.lower() == "n":
                seller_info_menu()
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the parameters inside the tuple of the 2nd argument of `cursor.execute()` must be the same as the order of the `?` paceholders:

```
cursor.execute(updateseller, (Phone, Email, Address, sellername))
```